# Symmetrical point with respect to a plane

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have the point $A = (10,0,20)$, and I want the coordinates of its symmetrical point $B$ with respect to the plane $\pi = \begin{cases} x=2+3\alpha+\beta\\y=\alpha\\z=\alpha + 2\beta \end{cases}$, how can I do that? Look at the image:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKEAr.png)

[These are the question's alternatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JVGZ.png)
$(2,20,24);\;(4,15,23);\;(-2,30,26);\;(0,25,25)$

Comment: Use the facts that the line joining $A$ and $B$ is perpendicular to plane and the midpoint of $AB$ lies on the plane.

Comment: i understood that but i still don't get it

Comment: Do you know what is the cross-product? This is one alternative how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Long solution**

The cartesian equation of the plane is $$\pi: 2x-5y-z-4=0$$

The parametric equations of the line $r$ which is perpendicular to $\pi$ and contains $A=(10,0,20)$ are $$r:\begin{cases}x=10+2t\\y=-5t\\z=20-t\end{cases}$$. This line also contains $B$ so the coordinates of $B$ are $(10+t,-5t,20-t)$ for some $t\in \Bbb R$.

The cartesian equations of $r$ are $$r:\begin{cases} y-5z+100=0 \\x+2z-50=0\end{cases}$$

The line $r$ intersects $\pi$ in the middle point $M$ between $A$ and $B$. Let's find the coordinates of $M$ by solving :$$\begin{cases} 2x-5y-z-4=0\\y-5z+100=0 \\x+2z-50=0\end{cases}$$

Once you've found the coordinates of $M=(x_M,y_M,z_M)$ you solve for $t$ $$||A-M||=||B-M||$$ $$\sqrt{(10-x_M)^2+(-y_M)^2+(20-z_M)^2}=\sqrt{(10+t-x_M)^2+(-5t-y_M)^2+(20-t-z_M)^2}$$

Lastly substitute the value of $t$ you've just found in $(10+t,-5t,20-t)$ to find the coordinates of $B$.

**Shorter solution**

For each alternative point $P$ that the exercise gives you, calculate the vector $\vec{AP}$ and check if it's parallel to the vector $(2,-5,-1)$ which is perpendicular to the plane. If this is true for more then one of the alternatives calculate the distance of $A$ and $P$ from $\pi$ and check if they're equal. The one alternative that verifies these two conditions ($\vec {AP}$ perpendicular to $\pi$ and $A$ and $P$ at the same distance from $\pi$) is $B$.

Answer (score 0):

An equation of the plane is
\begin{equation}
x = 2 + 3 y + (z-y)/2 \Longleftrightarrow 2 x - 5 y -z -4 = 0
\end{equation}
Let $A = (x_0,y_0,z_0) = (10, 0, 20)$ and $B = (x_1, y_1, z_1)= A + t (2, -5, -1)$ because the vector $(2, -5, -1)$ is perpendicular to the plane. We have $2 x_0-5 y_0 -z_0 - 4 = -4$, hence we need $2 x_1-5 y_1 -z_1 - 4 = +4$ in order to have the midpoint $(A + B)/2$ on the plane. This implies $t = 8/30 = 4/ 15$, hence
\begin{equation}
x_1 = 10 + \frac{8}{15}=\frac{158}{15}\qquad
y_1 = -\frac{20}{15}\qquad z_1 = 20 -\frac{4}{15} = \frac{296}{15}
\end{equation}

Comment: May I ask you why you didn't write it in the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$? How did you find it?

Comment: I took the first equation $x=2 + 3\alpha + \beta$. I replaced $\alpha$ with $y$ according to the second equation and $\beta$ with $(z-y)/2$ according to the third equation. It could be used as a general method: eliminate the parameters in the 3 equations, the remaining equation is the equation of the plane.

Comment: Ok I used the same method, I was just wondering why you had left that $/2$ there instead of writing the final espression $2x-5y-z-4=0$. Thanks!